# Using Blender for 2D Art

Tags: rendering

I wanted to post this question on blenderartist.org but, for some bizarre reason, the Compositing and Post Processing parts of the forum do not allow you to create threads in them. How inconvenient.

Anyhow I have seen a few videos every now and then on YouTube where an artist does a quick sculpt in **ZBrush**, does a quick render and throw it into **Photoshop**. There are two ways this processing works:

1. The model has some materials applied and is painted over, using the base as a colour palette and perspective guide.
2. It has a basic matcap applied and the model is used as a reference for drawing/tracing over, as well as being used for proportions and perspective.

I don't own ZBrush or Photoshop; instead I use Blender and GIMP, which are free opensource alternatives. Is there a "right" way of doing this same process except with the two opensource softwares? I don't believe this kind of workflow has been covered before so I apologize if I have not articulated my question very well.

My reason for asking this question is so that I can use Blender to help compose a 3d scene for 2D artwork.

EDIT: Here's a video example of what I'm aiming for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQBozQf0qyw . But not just scenes of course; characters also.

Comment: Can you link an example of what you've liked from youtube?

Comment: You can do both techniques you list, as well as you can render out to the same camera size as your intended project and then bring that image in as a mask image in texture paint tool, and then you can paint it in with an easy inversion for concentrating on highlights or shadows. You can also render with a few different materials from the same camera position and then stencil between the images in the texture stack with procedural texture brushes, etc. My thread on all things I have learned is here: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?291907-Craig-s-2d-painting-in-Blender&highlight=